# Django forms with Foreign keys

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have scenario in which a user can have multiple books. I can create two different models for user and books and relate them using foreign keys (or one-to-many will be right way ?).
I have created a django forms for User model but when i do like this **{{form.as_p}}** in templates only user model fields is shown not books field.

I want that *with user fields my books model filed also displayed (like book names field more then once because he can have multiple books)* , Please let me know if it is possible using django forms/models or I have to user simple html forms with jquery and then save data in models.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
my models :

```
class Product(models.Model):
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices = settings.CATEGORIES)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices = settings.CURRENCY)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Prices(models.Model):
    products = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    prices = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.id
```

Comment: Please post your `models.py`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Edit my question , plz check

Comment: I don't see any User model relationship?

Comment: I have just explain the general scenario in my question .

Comment: like a product can have multiple prices and when user create a product , he can add multiple prices for that product . PLz check the edited code

Comment: You need to use [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

Answer (score 4):

if you are creating a form for Prices, try putting this in your model form:

```
products = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all())
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. I have edit my question with my models. can you tell me how I can do for these models.

Comment: What happens if the contents of the queryset change after the Python file containing the form was imported? The class attributes are instantiated at import time, so I'm not sure if this would work the way I'd expect it to...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add required fields in meta class such as

```
class ThreadForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Thread
        fields = ('Books', 'User')
```

Please understand the work flow to use foreign keys in model form [here](http://charlesmurray.ca/2012/09/24/django-modelforms-with-foreign-keys/).