# Page with forms for multiple foreign keys

Tags: django, django-forms

Given the following (simplified) models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class Weight(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, verbose_name="Person")
    date = models.DateField("Date")
    weight = models.DecimalField("Weight", max_digits=4, decimal_places=1)
```

I'm looking for a way to add weight information for a certain group of Persons at once, which I specify through e.g. GET params. The length of the list of Persons and the Persons in the list can vary.

So I'm looking to generate a page like:

```
Person 1     Date: <pick date>     Weight: <enter weight>
Person 2     Date: <pick date>     Weight: <enter weight>
Person 3     Date: <pick date>     Weight: <enter weight>
Person 4     Date: <pick date>     Weight: <enter weight>
Person 5     Date: <pick date>     Weight: <enter weight>

<Save>
```

This would then save weight information 5 times, once for each (different) Person.

I had a look at the [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/) and related documentation, but it looks like these are more for identical items and to on-the-fly generate more (e.g. creating multiple books under one author). In my case, each weight is bound to a certain Person, but the Person differs from line to line in the table.
I thought the `prefix` option on a formset (to use different formsets on one page) might be of help here, but looking at the documentation I'm not sure.

What is the Django way of doing things like these?

Other questions on SO referring [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493145/django-inline-forms-with-multiple-foreign-keys) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575078/django-forms-with-foreign-keys) [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145774/django-form-with-foreign-key) don't seem to match my use case, unless I'm overlooking something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use formset and give initial value for `person` field in each form:

forms.py

```
class WeightForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Weight
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
persons = Persons.objects.all()
data = request.POST or None

WeightFormSet = formset_factory(form=WeightForm, extra=0)
formset = WeightFormSet(data=data, initial=[{'person': p} for p in persons])

if request.method == 'POST':
     ...
```

Comment: Thanks, the `initial=[{'person': p} for p in persons]` is the catch indeed! 
Accessing the person's name is possible through `form.initial.person` (or `form.instance.person` when the page has reloaded due to errors).